# li increment - seems to stop at the third li

Tags: javascript, list, html-lists, increment

getting my head around javascript in adding an auto increment id for a list-item

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
var increments = document.getElementById("increment");
    var li = increments.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (i=0;i<li.length;i++) li[i].setAttribute("id", 'x' + i+1);
</script>
```

the problem is that after the second id of 'x21' it seems to drop off and not insert an id for the third, forth li.

maybe its staring at me in the face but i cant see it and my feeble mind is still learning

thnx for having a look

Comment: how many li elements do you have?  sounds like there are only 3 so you only have 01, 11, and 21.

Comment: this works fine for me (see http://jsfiddle.net/6CnLb/ ), the problem should be elsewhere.

Comment: You're also using global variables in your loop. This is generally a bad idea.  
In your loop, write this instead  `for(var i=0,j=li.length;`

Comment: It would be interesting to see your html since it could be simple case of a type "incerment" instead of "increment" or something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TWDyp/).

It works ok for me. I changed the way you assign the id and used local variables instead of the global "i".

Also, better to always use curly brackets even for one line loops and if statements.

Comment: Parentheses are `(` and `)`. You probably meant: *curly brackets*:`{` and `}`.

Comment: Actually [parentheses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracket#Parentheses_.28_.29.2C_.5B_.5D.2C_or_.7B_.7D) are not only that, but bracket is a better understood term I guess.

Comment: Nice, remember the good practices: always declare variables with "var", and always use brackets for loops and if statements.